# Stardock's LogonStudio doesn't change the login screen background?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

I am using a Sony VAIO laptop (that comes with a custom login screen to begin with) running Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit.

I am trying to use Stardock's *LogonStudio* to change the background of my login screen.

I can add new images to the program, but no matter what I use (preloaded or my own images), it never manages to change the login screen background.

Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a VAIO as well and it looks like getting this to work requires a small registry edit:

1. Go to `Start->Run` and type in `regedit`.
2. [Back up your registry](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Back-up-the-registry) using `File->Export`.
3. In the tree on the left, navigate to the following key:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background`
4. Double-click on the `OEMBackground` key and change its value to `0`.
5. Click `OK`.

The logon screen background should now change as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 7 Logon Editing Guide](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/879070-windows-7-logon-editing-guide/)

That's a very useful link, that gives a good insight into the different things you can change on the logon screen, without installing Stardock's products. You mightn't like that idea, but using Resource Hacker is a lot easier once you get used to it. Use the registry entry in the answer above. The OEMBackground entry probably won't exist, so you'll have to create it as a 32bit D-WORD and set it to a value of 1.

Furthermore, you're going to need to create two new folders:
Go to Computer: Windows drive: Windows Directory: System32: oobe
Create folder with name: info
Create folder with name: backgrounds

Create a picture file <256KB and the same size as the resolution for your VDU (monitor).
Place picture file inside the new 'backgrounds' folder.

Leave the GUI. You don't have to restart or shutdown... you can log-off or switch user, or even just press Alt+Ctrl+Del, and it *should* show your new logon screen background.

Now we just need a script to randomly pick a picture out of a bunch of them...